# Verifying display of a pair of strings on a webpage in single line or different lines

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I need to verify a web page about a sportsperson, and I need to check if the sportsperson name displays on web page correctly. For instance, "Sir Andrew Barron Murray" is the name I need to check throughout the web page and the name should get display in each and every instance in a single line. It should not display like, Sir Andrew in one line and Barron Murray in the second line. The entire name has to display in a single line.

I tried with a body of the text and checked the `IndexOf` each letter, but didn't work out. The other solution I could think of is getting the exact coordinates of each word in a string and compare to each other. But I am not sure how to get the coordinates of text in a web-element. I understand that we can use getLocation, but this would get the web-element location but not the exact text within a web-element.

Comment: Coordinates within string will not help you. You can only rely on exact screen position of each word in relation to others.

Comment: Thanks, but not sure how to get the screen/webpage coordinates of a text. Using getBoundingClientRect() we can get only the element coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

In JS you could fill the Element with a character like 'a' via `element.innerHTML`, then get its height with `element.getBoundingClientRect().height`.
Then you insert the name back into the element and do the same again. You'll find that the second height is a multiple of the first one.

```
var text = element.innerHTML;
var one_line_height = element.getBoundingClientRect().height;
element.innerHTML = text;
var current_height = element.getBoundingClientRect().height; // must be recalled

console.log("Ratio: "+(current_height/one_line_height));
// should output 1 if the two are matching or 2, if its two lines
```

**Edit:** If the name is inside a text, wrap the name inside a div-wrapper with `display: inline;` and redo the calculation on the div element. That's because inline-elements break at a line-break.

Comment: Thanks John, but this would work if element contains only name of the sportsperson. Imagine, on the webpage there a paragraph of 4 lines and some portion of name is displayed in line 2 and rest in line 3. In this case the above code will return current_height = 4 and one_line_height as 1. IF the name is displayed in same line also it returns the same output.

Comment: @P.Johnson, the way you describe your task I feel like the simplest way would be to take screenshot of your page, and then do image recognition passes trying to find parts of name in increments (like "1st Part", then "1st Part 2nd Part" then "1st Part 2nd Part 3rd Part", etc.) and checking that for all words in name program can find all increments.

Comment: @P.Johnson Edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Using XPath

```
//*[contains(text(), 'your text you are searching for')]
```

If the text is on the page it will find it